# Does the ending change if I complete the Leviathan DLC?

Tags: mass-effect-3, me3-leviathan

In the course of the Leviathan DLC you learn some pretty important new facts about the reapers, namely that

> they, or at least the Catalyst, were created by the Leviathan species, and subsequently rebelled and nearly destroyed their creators.

Does this knowledge affect the game ending at all? Are there more conversation options with  the Catalyst, or does he/it offer up any additional information?

I would test this myself as I've just completed the DLC, but there are several hours of gameplay between this point and the end of the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are more conversation options with the Catalyst if you have completed the Leviathan DLC. Other than that, it's the same.

I found [this Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=77PNj0e_Iyk) which shows the final conversation with the Catalyst in more detail.